# Issue displaying timedate from database in UK format

Tags: php

I am trying show the datetime (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) from my mysql database in UK format but I can not get it to show correctly.

I have tried the following codes;

```
<?php $date = $info['created']; $bits = explode('-', $date); $date = $bits[2] . '/' . $bits[1] . '/' . $bits[0]; echo $date; ?>

<td><?=date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($info['created']))?></td>
```

The first code shows as 06 00:00:00/09/2020 and the second shows as 2020-09-06T00:00.

Comment: define "UK format" for us please. Broadly, the UK usually shows dates in dd/mm/yyyy format (achieves in PHP's format notation with `d/m/Y` - which would be clear hopefully if you'd studied the date format documentation for a few moments), but it's unclear if that's actually what you're referring to or not. There are other conventions around different types of date display, too.

Comment: Which UK format you want exactly? `d mmmm yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` and with hours and minutes or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)

*Most style guides follow the DMY convention by recommending d mmmm yyyy (sometimes written dd/mm/yyyy) format in articles*

```
<td><?=date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($info['created']))?></td> //dd/mm/yyyy
<td><?=date('d F Y H:i', strtotime($info['created']))?></td> //d mmmm yyyy
```

Comment: @ADyson Notice the capital `M`, the first returns 12, the seconds returns `Dec`

Comment: Sorry I spotted that and deleted the comment before you even replied! But still, `d/m/Y H:i` doesn't output  d mmmm yyyy as you state. and `d/M/Y H:i` doesn't output dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: True, I've fixed the typo

Comment: `d/M/Y H:i` still doesn't output d mmmm yyyy though. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1433a57f790624302a3c1ad0fe5ddd97d9753848 . Did you test your code?

Comment: Replaced the `M` with `F` to return the full `month`

Comment: It still has slashes in it though, which isn't how you'd write a date like that. And if a date was being written longhand like that, then by common convention in the UK the time would probably be written as `2:36 PM` or similar, rather than in 24hr format.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help :)